# Excel disable automatic converting text to date

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I copy data which are in the format like 01-01 to an excel file, it gets automatically convert to a date string. However do I preserve exactly the original text, in this case 01-01? (I need to copy lots of this data in this format, I don't want to manually add ' to each of the data to convert them back.)

please see attachment for details
[image]

Comment: Format the cell as text BEFORE pasting the data.

Comment: can you show me an example?
I tried to change the format to 'text', but after I paste, the format gets overwritten. If you meant a 'user defined format', can you show me the correct format string?

Comment: Do you have anything like `01-255`? Like *01* to *09* left of the hyphen and three digits after?

Comment: BTW, to use the *preformat as text* trick you need to first set the destination cells as Text then copy then right-click the destination cells and choose *Match destination formatting*.

Comment: >>BTW, to use the preformat as text trick you need to first set the destination cells as Text then copy then right-click the destination cells and choose Match destination formatting. 
>> it worked. I missed this step. Thanks so much for pointing this out!!